# How do you calculate the free space wavelength of an electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrons, wavelength

The only thing I know about an electron is that its mass is $m_0 = 9.109 * 10^{-31} kg.$

How would you calculate the wave length from here?

Ok, using de Broglie's relation we have

$p = h/\lambda_e$ => $E = h\nu = p^2/(2m_o)$ => $2m_o(\lambda_e)^2 = h/\nu$

But I don't know the frequency of the electron...

Comment: No,you cannot calculate wavelenght by just knowing the mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have velocity information on the electron, then it doesn't have momentum, so any equation involving p can't be used. Just convert the electron's rest mass to energy directly, using E=mc²

Comment: wait so I can use $E = mc^2$ even though electron doesn't move at the speed of light?

Comment: @Math Newb :$E=mc^2$,just mean an object with mass $m$,has energy equal to $E=mc^2$ even ifthe object has no momentum.If it has momentum then the equation become $E^2-(pc)^2=(mc^2)^2$.
The equation has nothing to do with the fact that electrons donot move at the speed of light.